# In fortran, in what scope should I place 'use [module]' statements for the best performance?

Tags: module, fortran

Say I have a subprogram in a Fortran program/module that uses another module. Will the performance of this subprogram be better if I place the 'use' statement within the subprogram or at the program/module scope?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If, by "performance", you mean execution speed, then **No.**

Positioning of the statement will make no difference.

Comment: Yes I meant execution speed, thank you. So, in the case that 'use' is in the subprogram, is it true that the module is loaded at the program/module scope but access to its components is restricted to that subprogram? There is no reinitializing of the module upon subsequent subprogram calls, and local/global scope makes no difference?

Comment: There is nothing as (re)initialization of modules in Fortran, every executable code must be explicitly called and all module variables are implicitly `save`. The `use` statement does not "load" the module, it just provides access to the module procedures, types and variables and it happens at compile time.